# search mysql using checkboxs?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have been working on this for hours to no avail.

I'm trying to create an advanced search feature for my site using PHP and mysql.

the advanced search only has checkboxes in it.

the checkboxes look like this:

```
<form action="search.php"  method="POST" id="myForm"/>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="small"/></td>
    <td>Small</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="large"/></td>
    <td>Large</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="xlarge"/></td>
    <td>X-Large</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="xxlarge"/></td>
    <td>XX-Large</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="red"/></td>
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="black"/></td>
    <td>Black</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="keyword[]"  value="white"/></td>
    <td>White</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**my MYSQL database looks like this:**

**products table:**

```
id  product_name  price  
5     shirt        20
6     shoe         70
```

I have an attributes table where i store the colors and size of the products.

**this table looks like this:**

```
idc  id  product_name  colors   sizes 
1     5     shirt        red     
2     5     shirt        back
3     5     shirt        white
4     5     shirt                small
5     5     shirt                medium
6     5     shirt                Large
7     6     shoe         brown
8     6     shoe         black
9     6     shoe                   5 
10    6     shoe                   6
11    6     shoe                   7
```

in my search.php page, I have this code :

```
include "config/connect.php"; 
$searchList = "";


foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
$sql ="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id= ATTRIBUTES.id
WHERE (
     ATTRIBUTES.size LIKE '%".$c."%' OR
     ATTRIBUTES.color LIKE '%".$c."%'
      )";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
}

//var_dump($query);

$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$i=0; // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
    }
}
```

the code above doesn't return anything and I'm keep getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

which means there is something gone wrong after my sql query!

so I did `var_dump($query);` and that gave me `bool(fales)`.

not much of a help as that means the same thing as the first error!

so could someone please help me out with this issue?

any advise and help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've changed my code to this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
include "config/connect.php";
$searchList = "";
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                $sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }   $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        }
    }
//echo $sql;//Remove after testing
}
//var_dump($query);

$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$i=0; // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
    }
}
?>
<?php echo $searchList; ?>
```

but the code above gives me the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: query in on line 23 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on line 23
```

am I in the right direction?

EDIT:

THIS CODE RETURNS THE DATA FROM MYSQL DATABASE BUT THE INFORMATION IS WRONG!

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                $sql .= $clause."`sizes` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Check that the query ran fine.
        if (!$query) {
            print "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($db_conx);
        } else {
            // Use $query inside this section to make sure $query exists.
            $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $i=0; // count the output amount
            if ($productCount > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                   $id = $row["id"];
                   $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                   $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add error checking to the query itself and you'll see that there are syntax issues which need to be fixed.

Comment: Do a dump on POST['keyword'].Also your mysqli query will run all statements but what you pass to mysqli_num_rows will be just the results of the last iteration,The parentheses in WHERE are unnecessary.

Comment: One issue I see is that you're running the SQL query for each keyword, instead of running one SQL query with all the keywords. You are currently just really running the very last keyword, ignoring the previous ones.

But anyways, getting a FALSE for $query means your SQL statement failed. Try printing out mysqli_error($db_conx) and see what it says.

Comment: @BlahArgh, i did `echo mysqli_error($db_conx);` but this doesn't echo anything at all.

Comment: `$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);` shouldn't that be `$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);`? `$query` isn't defined, which is why you're getting that notice. Plus `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))` to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC))`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, no that is wrong. I always use $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); as I am defining it like this: $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); and it always works fine. that is not the issue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this and see what you get:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
include "config/connect.php";
$searchList = "";
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `yt`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON yt.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE '%$c%' OR ATTRIBUTES.colors LIKE '%$c%')";
                $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        print "SQL Query: $sql<br />"; //<-- Debug SQl syntax.
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        var_dump($query); //<-- Debug query results.
        // Check that the query ran fine.
        if (!$query) {
            print "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($db_conx);
        } else {
            // Use $query inside this section to make sure $query exists.
            $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $i=0; // count the output amount
            if ($productCount > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                   $id = $row["id"];
                   $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                   $searchList .= ''.$product_name.'';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php echo $searchList; ?>
```

Edited: Fixed wrong column names.
Something like that, perhaps?

Comment: ERROR: Unknown column 'small' in 'where clause'

Comment: I'm just being silly now. I've been searching for the column's name!

Comment: Hehe, ya, seems like it.

Comment: oh wow, you beat me to it. I just posted my own solution as well. thanks mate. I'm gonna give your solution a try as well and see which one works better.

Comment: nope, neither solutions worked lol. I deleted mine. your solution returns this: ERROR: Unknown column 'ATTRIBUTES.size' in 'where clause'

Comment: my solution returns something but wrong information for some reason.

Comment: Oh, you named the column "sizes", not "size". I'll fix my answer. Gah, and "colors", not "color".

Comment: That's because of the "%" wildcard chars. If you just want "large", not "xxlarge", for example, then just do ATTRIBUTES.sizes LIKE '$c'. Remove the "%" chars. Same goes for colors, if you want.